# CSS width:auto going full length when not supposed to

Tags: html, css

My problem is when I do `width:auto` the div goes full length but I only want it to go the width of the divs that are inside it.

HTML:

```
<div class="vidswraper">
<div>
<div class="videoimage">
<img src="images/icon1.jpg" height="100" width="100">
<p class="price">21.09</p>
</div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="videoimage">
<img src="images/icon2.jpg" height="100" width="100">
<p class="price">1.99</p>
</div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="videoimage">
<img src="images/logo.jpg" height="100" width="100">
<p class="price">12.12</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.vidwraper {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: auto;
   height: 110px;
}
```

When I do inspect element it shows me this:

[image: Inspect]

which means that the width is not covering the 3 divs that are in the `.vidswraper`.

NOTE: the divs in side are `float:left;` and the width is `width:110px`.

Comment: @Haza, as an answer to your "question" (now deleted) answer: It's not a great question, but it is the **right kind** of question. As opposed to the **I need this... (because I don't know how to code it and I'm not even trying)** type of questions, which are plague-ing SO.

Comment: Just writing down the names is enough, don't worry about referencing. Trust me, people providing answers on SO do come and revisit them. Your thanks would not have been unnoticed by the ones who answered./. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the default behavior of blocks, they want to fill all available space.

Instead, it seems you want the [shrink-to-fit algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float).

There are several ways to achieve this:

- `display: table`

  Note this has a `table` inner display layout model, which may be problematic if the contents are tabular elements. Otherwise they will be wrapped in an anonymous table cell.
- `display: inline-block`

  This has the problem that produces an inline-level box instead of a block one. If you have several of they, they may be stacked horizontally instead of vertically.
- `display: inline-table`, `display: inline-flex`, `display: inline-grid`

  These have the same problem as `display: inline-block`. Additionally, they have an inner display role layout model which is neither `flow` nor `flow-root`, this can be problematic.
- `float: left`

  This has the problem that the box is taken out of flow. You may need to use clearfix or make the parent to establish a block formatting context in order to solve this.

  Additionally, a bunch of floated elements will be stacked horizontally. Use clearance to prevent that.
- `width: fit-content`

You may also be interested in `width: max-content` or `width: min-content`. But, together with `width: fit-content`, they may not be widely supported yet.

Alternatively, you could try placing your element in an special layout model. For example, if you place it in a flex container, it will become a flex item and thus (by default) won't grow to fill available space.

Comment: thank you all you guys thanks i really need help with that

Answer (score 4):

Divs are block level elements. That means they are full width by default. You have to give your divs an explicit width if you don't want them full width.

Comment: so you are saying that i can not use width:auto

Comment: you can use it on the container if you give your inner-divs a width. `,videoimage{ width: 5em; }`

Answer (score 2):

`width:auto` actually means: **"browser decides width"**.

For any DOM element that has the default `display` set to `block`, `width:auto` is translated to **100% of the parent's content area width**.