# CSS to limit the maximum value of width?

Tags: css

I am putting some texts in a container (say `<p/>`). I want to set a "maximum width" property, such that

1. when the content length is smaller than the "maximum width" (say `80%`), the container width will be roughly the same as the content length;
2. when the content length is larger than the "maximum width", the container width will be the "maximum width", and the content will be wrapped.

In either case I will add `margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto`, so that my content will always be centered.

Is this possible, or are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code would be

```css
width: max-content;
max-width: 80%;
```

However, `max-content` is not widely supported yet. So you can try the similat `fit-content`, which can be achieved with `width: auto`, and floating or inline-level display. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34602107/1529630) for details.

Comment: Both `max-content` and `fit-content` work fine in my case.

Answer (score 0):

What you need :

```
p{
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:200px; /* Random value here */
}
```

Good luck